# each_with_index condition statement ruby

Tags: ruby, indexing, conditional-statements

I am a programming neophyte so I apologize if this is more simple than it seems. I've searched around and only found individual answers for each_with_index and conditions, never together.

My goal is to iterate through an array and perform a single action based on the index. My first draft looked a little something like this:

```
@word_array.each_with_index do |word, index|
  if index % 2 == 0
    word = "EVEN"
  end
end
```

Which works, but then I wanted to refactor it into a single line. My first attempt invoked an error due to it anticipating the else `:` part of the condition:

```
@word_array.each_with_index { |word, index| index % 2 == 0 ? word = "EVEN" }
```

I had tried it this way first thinking I may have some luck being as the block did not require an `else` condition, but obviously to no avail. I did discover I could use `nil` as a placeholder and have the code work:

```
@word_array.each_with_index { |word, index| index % 2 == 0 ? word = "EVEN" : nil }
```

However even after further reading up on each piece I'm uncertain whether or not having the `nil` there could potentially cause troubles in more complex situations even though it doesn't hamper my basic example here.

So to break it down into two questions:

1.) Is the `nil` going to bite me in the butt later?

2.) If so, is there a way to go about this using one line, or is my best bet to stick with the conditional block?

Comment: Why not `index % 2 == 0 and word = 'EVEN'`? Ternary `? .. :` is for A/B scenarios, not just A.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want this one-liner style:

```
word = 'EVEN' if index % 2 == 0
```

Using a ternary with a missing condition leaves people wondering why you didn't do this in the first place. A ternary is a great way to branch, like:

```
(index % 2 == 0) ? 'EVEN' : word
```

Comment: That first one is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

```
@word_array.each_with_index { |word, index| (index % 2 == 0) ? word = "EVEN" : nil }
```

should work. The ternary operator is easily confused.

1.) Is the nil going to bite me in the butt later?

Yes. Why not:

```
@word_array.each_with_index { |word, index| word = (index % 2 == 0) ? "EVEN" : "ODD" }
```